# Payment methods in configuration tab keep loading in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.9, payment-method

I'm trying to add a payment method. But after adding it I can't access the payment methods any more. I get the following errors from the log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:243:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT `core_translate`.`string`, `core_translate`.`translate` FROM `core_translate` WHERE (store_id IN (0 , :store_id)) AND (locale = :locale) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC";i:1;s:2919:"#0 /home/fitelegance/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /home/fitelegance/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /home/fitelegance/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_tr...', Array)
    #4 /home/fitelegance/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_tr...', Array)
    #5 /home/fitelegance/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #6 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Translate.php(79): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #7 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Translate->getTranslationArray(NULL, 'en_US')
    #8 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php(142): Mage_Core_Model_Translate->_loadDbTranslation(false)
    #9 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(146): Mage_Core_Model_Translate->init('adminhtml')
    #10 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(121): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_initTranslate()
    #11 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_loadPart('translate')
    #12 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(789): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->load()
    #13 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_App->loadArea('adminhtml')
    #14 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
    #15 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(51): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
    #16 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->preDispatch()
    #17 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
    #18 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #19 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #20 /home/fitelegance/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #21 /home/fitelegance/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:89:"/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/cb234a6ffb16ee3ba89eab23539e9421/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I removed all of the files for the payment methods but still am having the same issue. While I click on the Payment Methods tab, the browser keeps loading and creates the above errors in the log file.
Please suggest how can I solve this.

Comment: Please click edit and add and format your code.

Comment: tried formatting the codes but I'm not really familiar with these stuffs!

Comment: OK. I've cleaned it up. Hope that helps attract an answer! 